# Zend Url View Helper not working with Regex Routes

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route

I'm using Zend Framework 1.12 and have this route:

```
$router->addRoute('item_start',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
            '(foo|bar|baz)',
            array(
                'module'        => 'default',
                'controller'    => 'item',
                'action'        => 'start'
            ),
            array(
                1 => 'area'
            ),
            '%s'
        )
);
```

Problem is, when I call '/foo' and use the Url Helper in the View, it doesn't give me any parameters:

```
$this->url(array("page"=>1));
// returns '/foo' (expected '/foo/page/1')

$this->url(array("page"=>1), "item_start", true);
// also returns '/foo'
```

Any idea how to get the page-parameter into the URL? I can't use the wildcard like in the standard route, can't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to David's suggestions, you could change this route to use the standard route class, and then keep the wildcard option:

```
$router->addRoute('item_start',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
            ':area/*',
            array(
                'module'        => 'default',
                'controller'    => 'item',
                'action'        => 'start'
            ),
            array(
                'area' => '(foo|bar|baz)' 
            )
        )
);

// in your view:
echo $this->url(array('area' => 'foo', 'page' => 1), 'item_start');
```

Comment: Ah, completely forgot about the third parameter, to restrict the values. I'll go with your solution, seems more flexible, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your Regex route doesn't have a `page` parameter, so when the url view-helper ends up calling `Route::assemble()` with the parameters you feed it, it ignores your `page` value.

The two choices that come to mind are:

1. Modify your regex to include a (probably optional with default value) `page` parameter
2. Manage the `page` parameter outside of your route in the query string.

Comment: Thanks, 1. could get quite complex, when I want more parameters, but 2. is a good workaround, but requires a new Url Helper. Tim's solution seems to be the best in my case. :) (Sorry I can set only one answer to be the "correct one".)

Comment: No sweat, glad we could both help. Cheers. ;-)